# Разбор слова "времечко"!

Tags: морфемы

```
я учу русский язык за 5 класс, там было дано задание разобрать слово времечко
я рассуждал так:

    1)окончание -о это понятно
    2)слово время и времечко однокоренные и это явно, значит корень врем
    3)предполагаю, что суффикс -чк-, отсекаю его и получаю новое слово временный, значит предположил правильно
    4) и получаю два суффикса -е- и суффикс -чк-
в ответах указан суффикс -ечк-! 
где ошибка? почему рассуждения не верны? или может ошибка в ответе?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на вопрос: где ошибка в рассуждении? 
Вы не сделали самого главного, что нужно сделать с самого начала. Нужно определить лексическое значение, используя однокоренное (ищем ближайшего "родственника"). Времечко  - уменьшительно-ласкательное от "время". Сравниваем две основы. Они отличаются элементом "Ечк". Это суффикс.

Вы правильно сделали, что стали искать другие однокоренные слова. Но снова ошиблись. потому что слово "временный" имеет ближайшим родственником слово "время". (временный - тот, что на время). Сравниваем, находим суффикс -енн. Эти три слова не связываются в цепочку . Время -времечко, время- временный.

Answer (score 0):

Суффикс "ечк", конечно. Рассуждения не верны уже потому, что есть однокоренное время, в котором нет корневого "е". Ну это так, для школьников.
Реально, конечно, дело в том, что нет в русском языке суффикса **чк**. А в вашем примере "временный" точно также имеет суффикс "енн", т.е. некорневое е.